# How to protect the REST API in Slim framework

Tags: api, rest, mobile, slim

I have written an REST API in Slim framework. Currently the API is open Mode.
How Can I add the security to the API. By adding the API KEY or username or password.

Also this API will be used in Mobile application. how can we protect ?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [route middleware](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Middleware) to be sure that the requests have an API key (or whatever).

Example:

```
<?php
$checkApiKey = function () {
    return function () use () {
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        $apiKey = $app->request->post('apiKey');

        if ( Api::check($apiKey) ) { //your magic check on api key

            $app->flash('error', 'API Key not available');
            $app->redirect('/api/error');
        }
    };
};

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->group('/api', $checkApiKey(), function ($app) {
    //your amazing api routes...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. In that  group router, I have to add the other API request ( routers) . Correct ?                                          Also , Api::check is the custom function right ?

Comment: First answer is "Yes" and second answer is "Yes, you can use any logic you prefer there".